# (f)printf force zero numbers to display

Tags: c, format

I only write in C mostly because of machine control.
However, I have what is for me a real puzzler in writing to a CSV file.
This code works as expected:

```
fprintf(coutput,"%d,%+#5.2f\n",4095-i, ((double)(4095-i)/4095)*100);
```

but prints to the CSV output file for example:

```
45 4095   100
46 4095   100
47 4093 99.95
```

whereas I want to see:

```
45 4095 100.00
46 4095 100.00
47 4093  99.95
```

There are functions in C++/C# for string formatting but none I can find in C

Comment: sorry I clearly haven't sorted formatting text yet

Comment: The `fprintf()`  call you show prints two values, not three as you claim.  That makes your question confusing.

Comment: the first number is Excel's row number, not printed from fprintf()

Comment: Are you fighting Excel’s formatting?  If the first number is from Excel, then the lack of decimal places is because Excellent doesn’t display the trailing zeros unless you force it to do so.  No amount of tinkering with the data in the file will stop Excel formatting it as it sees fit.

Comment: Provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It should output

```
4095,+100.00
```

https://repl.it/repls/SturdyEnragedComputer

Are you sure you are outputting to the correct file?

To have what you want:

```
4095 100.00
```

https://repl.it/repls/GleamingPlainQuery

```
printf("%d %6.2f\n",4095-i, ((double)(4095-i)/4095)*100);
```

Comment: I edited the code to  printf("%d %6.2f\n",4095-i, ((double)(4095-i)/4095)*100);     No effect, still shows 4095  100.  To (re)check correct file I first deleted the CSV then reran my code.

Comment: are you using standard C?  How about running it on the REPL website? Does it behave differently from your computer? What if you use that simple program in the REPL and compile and run it on your machine?

Comment: Code:Blocks 17:12  gcc (tdm-1) 5.1.0 compiler on 32bit Windows 7.  Can I get any more standard?

Comment: so can you compare to the REPL website and see which one is showing what and which one is behaving weird?

Comment: See if I can find time. Looks like I have to learn a new language! :(